# system() and popen() not available

Tags: c++, linux, bash, busybox

I need to run a shell script from C++ code on Linux machine. I've tried using system() and popen() functions. When I test them on dev machine all works ok, but when I try same functions on actual device - I get error 127. From information a have so far it means, that script interpreter is not available, but actually machine has busybox installed with ash interpreter in it. I may run same commands via command line - no problem at all. When I try doing it from code I get:

```
Command: sh -n '/home/test/test.sh' Status: 127
```

What may be the reason for such behavior? 
Is it possible that I reached some sort of kernel limits?

Code example1:

```
int Files::CallShell( std::string& command )
{
    int status = 0;
    char buff[512] = { 0 };
    FILE *in;

    if ( !(in = popen( command.c_str(), "r") ) )
    {
        printf( "Can't execute: %s\n", command.c_str() );
        status = -1;
    }

    while ( fgets( buff, sizeof(buff), in) != NULL )
    {
        printf( "Result: %s\n", buff );
    }

    status = pclose( in );
    status = ( WIFEXITED( status ) )? WEXITSTATUS( status ) : status;

    printf("Command: %s Status: %d\n", command.c_str(), status );

    return status;
}
```

Code example2:

```
int Files::CallShell2( std::string& command )
{
    int status = 0;

    status = system( command.c_str() );
    status = ( WIFEXITED( status ) )? WEXITSTATUS( status ) : status;
    printf("Command: %s Status: %d\n", command.c_str(), status );

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Which OS is installed on your dev machine and on your target machine? Also, what else your install script is doing? i.e. how can you be sure that it's your code that causes the issue?

Comment: Dev: x64 Xubuntu machine. 
Target: Embedded system with ARM6, Linux 3.0.9 with some RT patches, busybox 1.21 and some custom made services. 
I do understand that target device is very specific, but any clue will  do.

Comment: Have you included the relevant headers?

Comment: Check that `/bin/sh` works on the target machine. Or consider using `fork` + `execve`; also use `strace` on the target machine

Comment: Both /bin/sh and /bin/su works just fine.

Comment: As I know system is defined in stdlib, so of course it was included. Also - missing header would rise compilation error, not runtime error.

Comment: I would avoid `system`, and use `fork` and `execve`

Comment: I thought, that system actually is a fork with execve. Is there any difference?

Comment: @incogn1to `system` is much like `fork` followed by `execve /bin/sh -c ...`, where sh performs its own word splitting and such. So `system` is doing extra work you don't need here, and I agree that it would be useful to get rid of that extra work, but I'm not sure it will help you avoid the error you're getting.

Comment: Start your `/home/test/test.sh` script with `#!/bin/sh -vx` at least for debugging purposes.

Comment: Have you tried running `/bin/sh` instead of `sh`? You might have a different `PATH` set on the command-line and when running via `popen` or `system`.

Comment: You should fix your question title, the functions **are** "available" because you can call them, but they are not working as you expect. [Pstreams](http://pstreams.sf.net) does all this for you btw

Comment: Yes, I've also tried /bin/sh. Same result.

Comment: Be very, very sure that `/bin/sh` is a hardlink to the `busybox` executable, and has execute permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The `system()` library function executes `/bin/sh -c` to run the command passed. If `/bin/sh` does not exist, or if `ash` does not parse parameters in the same way, you will get this error. You may be able to either link `/bin/sh` to `/bin/ash`, or perhaps better implement your own version of `system()` with `fork()` and one of the `exec` family of functions, which could invoke `ash` rather than `sh`.

Comment: ...well, since it's busybox ash, it may not even be `/bin/ash`. Better just to invoke busybox as `sh` -- it'll recognize `argv[0]` and take the appropriate action.

Answer (score -1):

The "-n" switch is used to check the syntax of the shell scripts... if "-i" is not set. Check the manual page of the shell. As for the exit status check. From the manual page:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> Errors that are detected by the shell, such as a syntax error, will cause
>   the shell to exit with a non-zero exit status.  If the shell is not an
>   interactive shell, the execution of the shell file will be aborted.  Oth‐
>   erwise the shell will return the exit status of the last command exe‐
>   cuted, or if the exit builtin is used with a numeric argument, it will
>   return the argument.

Comment: This line is just an example. Same status is returned on any other command.